# Imported namespaces in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks

I am importing a Objective-C framework into Swift that uses namespaces. Eg:

```
namespace A {

    struct B {
       ......
    };

     class C { 
        ....
    };
}
```

I am unable to declare a variable of type B or C. How does Swift interoperate with namespaces?

Answer (score 3):

Objective C does not support namespaces or classes. The code you quoted is Objective C++. Swift - Objective C++ interop is not supported:

> You cannot import C++ code directly into Swift. Instead, create an Objective-C or C wrapper for C++ code.

(Quote from [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/)).